# Reverse Phone Number Lookup Without Country Code

Tags: libphonenumber

I have been using googles libphonenumber to perform validation of US phone numbers. Now I am needing international support for all countries. Is it possible to reverse lookup a phone numbers country code using libphonenumber?

Say the DB has saved UK number +448456779463. Is it possible to libphonenumber to detect if that number is UK? It appears I can only check the validity of the number provided I know its country of origin first. But what to do if you have numbers and don't know its country of origin?

Comment: allen, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio's [Lookup](https://www.twilio.com/lookup) tool can likely be of some help here.

It will return a country code based upon number input alone and you can retrieve additional information about a phone via the API.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups

[*Disclosure: I work for Twilio*]

Comment: Twilio lookup is too expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `libphonenumber`.

Following is example in python

```
import phonenumbers
number = "+44XXXXXXXX"
obj = phonenumbers.parse(number)

# get line type
phonenumbers.number_type(obj)

# validate phone
phonenumbers.is_valid_number(obj)

# validate phone for region
phonenumbers.is_valid_number_for_region(obj, "GB")

# get country name
from phonenumbers.geocoder import country_name_for_number
country_name_for_number(obj, "en")
```

I think following is what you looking exactly,

```
from phonenumbers.geocoder import region_code_for_number
phonenumbers.is_valid_for_region(obj, region_code_for_number(obj))
```